# can't run docker after installing systemd in WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd

I am trying to use systemctl in WSL, so I use the [script from Github](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/blob/master/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.sh) to install systemd, but after the installation, I can't run the docker desktop from WSL.
The docker desktop is installed on Win10, but before I install systemd, I could run docker from WSL. Why can't I run it now？ Is there any way to fix it?

I have chosen `Enable integration with my default WSL distro` in the docker desktop

Here is the output when I try ot use docker:

```
(base) alma@DESKTOP-8EH3B7O:~$ docker --version

The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro.
We recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

For details about using Docker Desktop with WSL 2, visit:

https://docs.docker.com/go/wsl2/
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may not answer your question directly (or it may), a few notes that are applicable to it:

- First, as a general rule, if you are using code you found on Github, there's typically a place there to file [issues](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/issues) against it.  I'd recommend starting there, since those most familiar with the code will see it.
- Also, check out the existing issues.  [One in particular](https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/issues/80) (currently) near the top looks *similar* to this, in that it is a path issue.  It may be related to what you are seeing.
- In general, running Systemd enablement scripts can drastically change the behavior of WSL, so this error isn't necessarily unexpected.  You also don't mention what distribution you are using in WSL, and each distro implements Systemd differently (different services, unit files, etc.).  It's tough for any one Systemd enablement script to keep up with all distros, releases, and changes.  I do see that the most recent check-in (other than the Readme) was 2 years ago, so that's quite a while given the speed at which distros (and WSL) change.
- You might want to read my [Ask Ubuntu answer regarding Systemd on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986), including some alternatives, as well as why I recommend against using it unless you really know what it is changing (so you can debug issues like this yourself).
- If you *really* must have Systemd, consider the [Genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) script.  It is (currently) well maintained and updated.  But also, do as the maintainer requests and ...

  > Before you install genie for the first time, read ALL of this page.
- Alternatively, [Distrod](https://github.com/nullpo-head/wsl-distrod) is well maintained and respected in the community, but it's a bit more "invasive", so understanding what it changes is a bit more complicated (IMHO) than Genie.

  Note that I have not directly used Genie or Distrod myself, but I have studied the code on both quite extensively for my own understanding of Systemd on WSL.